# Scripts are not called until I login from wordpress backend

Tags: admin, javascript, login

I am enqueuing custom scripts for slider in header.php but it is not working until I login from backend. I am working on localhost. The code is

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title><?php bloginfo('title');?> | <?php bloginfo('url'); ?></title>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php wp_enqueue_script('bjqs-1.3', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bjqs-1.3.js'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('bjqs-1.3.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bjqs-           1.3.min.js'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_style('bjqs', get_template_directory_uri().'/bjqs.css'); ?>
<?php //wp_enqueue_style('demo', get_template_directory_uri().'/demo.css'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery.secret-source.min',     get_template_directory_uri().'/jquery.secret-source.min.js'); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the code in functions.php not in header.php.

```
<?php

function my_script(){ 
// put wp_enqueue_script here 
?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('bjqs-1.3', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bjqs-1.3.js'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('bjqs-1.3.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bjqs-           1.3.min.js'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_style('bjqs', get_template_directory_uri().'/bjqs.css'); ?>
<?php //wp_enqueue_style('demo', get_template_directory_uri().'/demo.css'); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery.secret-source.min',     get_template_directory_uri().'/jquery.secret-source.min.js'); ?>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script');

?>
```

See here for detail, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script.